# awk multiple field seperators?

Tags: awk

I have a large file with lines like so

```
chr1    HAVANA  gene    11869   14409   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2";
```

I want to extract ENSG00000223972.5, DDX11L1, chr1, 11869 and 14409.
I have succeeded in the first two by:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\""}; {print $2"\t"$6}' file.txt
```

I'm struggling to now extract the chr1, 11869 and 14409 as this will need a different feild seperator? How is this done on the same ;line??

Answer (score 1):

Try to use following command to extract what you want,

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\"";OFS="\t"}; {split($1,a,/[\ ]*/); print a[1],a[4],a[5],$2,$6}' file.txt
```

Brief explanation,

- `split($1,a,/[\ ]*/`: split `$1` into the array `a`, and the separators would be regex `/[\ ]*/`
- Print the split content stored in `a` as you desired.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'[ "]+' -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, $4, $5, $10, $16}' file
chr1    11869   14409   ENSG00000223972.5       DDX11L1
```